# Relative frequency in java

Tags: java, frequency

I want to create a program to help me with the statistics, but I'm having problems from the beginning and I'm making a huge mess to calculate the relative frequency of an array with random numbers and only one dimension.

For example to generate these numbers:

> {3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4}

I want that the program tell me that  the `3` is repeated 2 times, the `4` 3 times and `5` 5 times

I've created a class to sort these values ​​in order to calculate the median, the first and third quartile, but I still do not know how to find the frequency in order to calculate other values

Thanks for your time

PS: Do not know if this affects anything but I'm using **netbeans**

Comment: So you want the program to lie to you?

Comment: [Counting number of items in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647232/count-the-occurrences-of-items-in-arraylist)

Comment: Use a `Map<Integer,Integer>`

Comment: +1 @MrSmith42 i would second that

Comment: @RobinChander if the number range is relatively small, I think my solution is a good one.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for this for sure: [Collections: frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)

If you dont have a Collection, convert your array to list first:

```
Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(yourArray), new Integer(3))
```

Comment: So first he need to find all the different number. Then only he can use this for each of one. I guess.

Comment: No. Just use a loop and iterate through the elements in the array/list, calling the frequency method.

Comment: Then frequency would be called multiple times for same number.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Iterate over this then `new HashSet(Arrays.asList(yourArray))` (Again, call `Arrays.asList` only if your array is not already a List)

Comment: Lopez: Yeah HashSet would remove duplicates .But internally it would use for loops to perform these. i guess. And frequence API may also be of o(n) complexity. Check out my sollution.

Comment: I don't know with Oracle JDK but just checked OpenJDK 6 sources and yeah, its a full loop for the set creation and another one for the frequency. No chained loops at all though. Your solution has a chained loop and to be honest I'm not sure which one would be faster. I think it'd depend on the size of his array.
However, my solution is much clearer and also faster to implement ;)

Comment: It has chained loop but due to outer if condition , inner for loop would be executed only for distinct values from array. Without outer if , it would have been o(n^2) , but i think here, it won't. Anyways , I ll update with performace analysis in both the scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

If your range of numbers is relatively small, using an array of counters could be preferred.
For example, if your random numbers are in the interval `[1,5]` then you can use an array of size 5 to store and update the frequency counters:

```
int[] numbers = {3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4} ;
int[] frequencies = new int[5];

for(int n : numbers)
    frequencies[n-1]++;
```

**Output array** (`frequencies`):

```
1 1 2 2 3
```

**EDIT:**

This method can be applied to all ranges. For example, let's say you have numbers in the range `[500,505]`:

```
int[] frequencies = new int[6];

for(int n : numbers)
    frequencies[n-500]++;
```

Comment: What if I have an array like numbers = {1,2,10000,2,2,1,1000}; It would have a lot of wastege of memory.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi don't you know how to read a post? I said "if the range is small ..." then this solution is fine. but it seems you need to learn how to read before writing a comment.

Comment: Oh my bad. But don't you think its too static ?

Comment: what do you mean by "static"? with this solution, you can get the frequency of number _n_ via _frequencies[n-1]_. Isn't it cool?

Comment: i tried using your method because it seems more easy for me, but it give me some errors, i have this:

Comment: Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
Random r=new Random();

int max=25;
int min=5;
p=keyboard.nextInt();
int matrix[] = new int[p];
for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
    matrix[i]=number=r.nextInt(max-min+1)+minim; 
}                                                                    how can I fix your method to make it work with my array?

Comment: @DelShekasteh: you solution looks good, but it has tradeoffs.
What if the interval is [500, 505].
Here range is still 5 but your solution will require frequencies array of length 505. This is what PriyankDoshi meant by static

Comment: @RobinChander are you kidding me? if the interval is [500,505] you will populate the array with _frequencies[n-500]++;_ and access a number n's frequency with _frequency[n-500]_. It is not rocket science to understand this. And my solution has no trade-offs for small ranges. If you have a negative interval, e.g. [-5, -1], then you can populate the array with _frequencies[n+5]++;_.

Comment: @DelShekasteh: i want to shoot my self now. I thought you are always subtracting 1 up in your answer but din notice you are subtracting the interval's left bound!! Sincere apologies.
Would you mind editing your answer a bit so that I can give it a +1, its locked as of now for me

Comment: @RobinChander yes mate, edit is added and is waiting for your upvote =) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You can use a map for storing frequency like below :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Frequency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = { 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4 };
        int count = 1;
        // number,frequency type map.
        Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != -1) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                    if (nums[j] != -1) {
                        if (nums[i] == nums[j]) {
                            // -1 is an indicator that this number is already counted.
                            // You should replace it such a number which is sure to be not coming in array.
                            nums[j] = -1;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                frequencyMap.put(nums[i], count);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : frequencyMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(" Number :" + entry.getKey()
                    + " has frequence :" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

With Output :

```
 Number :1 has frequence :1
 Number :2 has frequence :1
 Number :3 has frequence :2
 Number :4 has frequence :2
 Number :5 has frequence :3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] numbers = {100, 101, 102, 103, 5 , 4, 4 , 6} ;

    Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int num: numbers){
        if(m.containsKey(num)){
            m.put(num, m.get(num)+1);
        }else{
            m.put(num, 1);
        }   
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " | Frequencey: " + entry.getValue());
    }
```