# How do I count the number of times "num" is present in rayList in this static method?

Tags: java

I'm not quite sure how to count the number of times "num" is present in the arraylist.

`public static int numCount (ArrayList<Integer> rayList, int **num**)`

Comment: `Collections.frequency(rayList, num)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative frequency in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266989/relative-frequency-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to iterate through your `ArrayList` to check every element. `for` loops and `arrays` usually go hand-in-hand.

While looping through the `ArrayList`, you would check if that element is equal to `num`. If they are `equal`, you would `increment` a counter variable by 1. If they are not equal, you do not increment the counter.

The counter variable will represent the number of times `num` is present in the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `numCount` method, you want to pass your `ArrayList` and the number you are checking for in your counting function. Use the Enhanced `For Loop` (Of the form "`for(int val: rayList){...}`") to automatically compare val(each pertinent element in `rayList`) to the number you want to find. Increment a declared counter as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, note that posting code is OK, but just be sure to explain it well. We try to avoid code-dump questions and answers both.

Answer (score 0):

```
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(rayList, num);
```