# How to get the number of occurrences of a string in an arraylist according to the user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Arraylist as follows , I need to count the number of occurrences for all of the elements in the Arraylist, knowing that the content of the Arraylist may change according to the user input. i.e : the user in the second time may enter(C and D)

```
ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();

letters.add("A");
letters.add("B");
letters.add("A");
letters.add("B");
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to count how many time an element is present in the list?

Comment: @Nermeen just to avoid extra coding, why don't you just use `HashMap`, and maintain count, as simple as that.

Comment: Yes I need to find how many A's and B's exist

Comment: Other than the naming of your variable as `letters`, nothing in your question text restricts the strings in the list to be just single-letter strings. Is that a restriction, or can the strings be words or entire sentences? If restricted, can they only be uppercase letters, and is lowercase allowed? Digits? Special characters? International letters like `ä`?

Comment: @Nermeen Please take more care when posting. Your example code was improperly formatted, and contained much  white space with more mysterious unprintable characters than printable characters.

Comment: @Nermeen Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Also a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14260134/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2647232/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7687062/642706), and more

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to keep track of the tokens (and counts). If you use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) it will preserve insertion order. I would use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate the `letters`; if the `map` doesn't currently contain the `letter` set it to `1` (otherwise increment the current count). Finally, print the `map`. Something like

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (String letter : letters) {
    map.put(letter, !map.containsKey(letter) ? 1 : 1 + map.get(letter));
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Also, you can *initialize* your `List` when you *declare* it like

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "A", "B");
```

Comment: But another question, how can to get a certain value from this map ,since I'm not so familiar with maps

Comment: @Nermeen `int countA = map.get("A");` **and** `int countB = map.get("B");`

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over the `ArrayList` and check if each element matches a particular `String`:

```
String test = //string you want to count occurrences of
int count = 0;
for (String s : letters) {
    if (s.equals(test)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think they want the count for every element. So, a HashMap<String, Integer> will be required to count occurence for every unique element within the list.

Comment: What is `letters`? Nothing in the question says that strings in the list are only single letters. That's just an example.

Comment: @Andreas `letters` is the `ArrayList`. It's right there in OP's code.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. Then, what is *"string you want to count occurrences of"*, when the question explicitly states that you don't know what to count since *"the Arraylist may change according to the user input"*?

Comment: @Andreas It could be inputted by the user or something, depending on what OP wants.

Comment: OP already said what is wanted: *"need to count the number of occurrences for all of the elements in the Arraylist"*. No extra input of what to count, because you have to count what is in the list.